# Membership Fee token displays in Email with 9 decimal points

Tags: civimail, civimember

Scheduled Reminder for renewing sponsorships uses membership fee token. However when sponsors receives the resultant email reminder the fee is displayed as XX.XXXXXXXXX.

Comment: This appears to be an open issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/377